# How to create a directory using os.mkdir()

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a directory using `os.mkdir()` or `os.makedirs()` as follows:

```
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)
```

This code runs fine, but I could see no directory created in the 'directory' path.
If I only write:

```
os.mkdir(directory)
```

it gives error message that directory already exists.

Comment: And what is `directory` set to then? Are you using relative paths at all?

Comment: We can't exactly take a peek at your file system, so what kind of answer are you expecting? I assure you that `os.mkdir` works.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following for a little more robust handling -- similar to how `mkdir -p` works on Linux:

```
def _mkdir(_dir):
    if os.path.isdir(_dir): pass
    elif os.path.isfile(_dir):
        raise OSError("%s exists as a regular file." % _dir)
    else:
        parent, directory = os.path.split(_dir)
        if parent and not os.path.isdir(parent): _mkdir(parent)
        if directory: os.mkdir(_dir)
```

If you try making a dir over a file, complain, otherwise, just make sure the dir exists.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary sure, but this is more helpful for learning what's involved.

Comment: @AbhayDoke the code doesn't really have any surprises.  you call `_mkdir('some_directory')` and if it's already a file, nothing is done.  if it's a file (e.g. you have a text file named '/home/abhay/code'), you'll get an error. else, the directory is split between parent folders and the end folder -- if there are missing folders between the parent folders and the end folder, you call your function to split and make the required directories.

if this answer helped you, consider upvoting or accepting.

Comment: i am facing the same problem now.. Is is something related to ubuntu?? Or is it due to PyCharm IDE i am using??

Comment: my answer will create directories.  please accept it.  do some more debugging to figure out what is happening on your machine.